# Python ModuleNotFoundError for local file

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm learning Python right now and I am stuck on this import issue.

In a folder I have a main.py and a second folder that has two scripts. `main.py` imports `apple.py` and `apple.py` imports `banana.py`. The problem is that when I run 'main.py' I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` because Python says there is no module named `banana`. I'm not sure if it is an import problem or something is wrong with the python implementation I downloaded (CPython 3.8).

```
project/
  L main.py
  L folder/
     L apple.py
     L banana.py
```

In main.py:

```
import folder.apple as app
```

In apple.py:

```
import banana as ban
```

Comment: add an empty __init__.py file to folder/, and in apple change it from folder.banana import banana as ban.

Comment: from 'folder.banana import banana as ban' to what?

Comment: sorry, I meant to write change if from "import banana as ban" to "from folder.banana import banana as ban" or "import folder.banana as ban". The first imports an object called banana from the banana file, the other imports everything in banana. Because when you call it from main.py the package "folder" is visible and contains banana. You could also change it to "import .banana as ban" the dot denotes that your importing something from the current folder, but its less common.

Comment: I added the __init.py__ in folder/ and used "import folder.banana as ban". I'm still getting the Module not found error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert you folder to package. To initialize your package you need to add an empty file with name `__init__.py`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

with this change your directory structure should look something like this,

```
project/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   folder/
      __init__.py
      apple.py
      banana.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively I think that another "hackey" solution would be adding these lines in `apple.py` before you import banana:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("folder")) # or whatever the name of the immediate parent folder is
```

I tried it out and it worked for me. Hope this helps you out!